# HP Compaq TC4200 problems

Tags: sound, touchpad, headphones

I have a hp compaq tc4200 and the headphone jack doesn't work it acts like nothing's plugged in.  I've tried any solution i could find and most did nothing at all at best and some forced me to re-install ubuntu.  I'm running 14.04 currently, the other issue is there is a button on the side that I used to use to disable the touchpad but upgrading to 14.04 it seems I've lost that setting somewhere.

I ran xev --event keyboard and it gave the following results when I pressed the button.

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x80, subw 0x0, time 28730704, (-94,220), root:(366,265),
    state 0x10, keycode 146 (keysym 0xff6a, Help), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    root 0x80, subw 0x0, time 28731138, (-94,220), root:(366,265),
    state 0x10, keycode 146 (keysym 0xff6a, Help), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I'd like to be able to press this button to disable my synaptics touchpad please?

As for the headphone jack I really don't know, I'm at my wits end with this, and to add insult to injury the built in speaker(s) is terrible.

Anyone who can help with either of my problems would really be a boon to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you look at the `alsamixer` if there is something muted? You can also try this http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Comment: Yes, I've tried the solutions in that link before as well, the sounds work through the main speaker.  The headphone jack output doesn't register and it's not listed in any of the gui menus in any mixer I've tried.  I ran the alsa-info script, the output is listed here.
[link](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=2d3f6c1e9080104860dcc9b8b23d3101b3e53ec1)

Comment: alsamixer doesn't give me any option to enable Headphone Jack Sense

Comment: I downloaded gnome alsa mixer and was able to enable headphone jack sense and the speakers mute when headphones are plugged in but I cannot turn up the volume of the headphone jack in either mixer and no output seems to be coming out of the jack aslamixer shows the jack now enabled but I cannot change the volume setting on it.

Comment: You can try this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191319&p=12869889#post12869889

Comment: I've downloaded qasmixer now, I don't see the dropdown menu the poster is talking about, I'll update again in a day or two while I fiddle with this and read more.  Forgot to mention all you guys are great for taking the time out of your day to help me out.  Thank you so much.

Comment: no real change with the sound beyond the fact that now when I plug in headphones it mutes all the audio.

Answer (score 1):

- From your alsa-info, there is a 'Headphone Jack Sense' control and a  'Phone' fader:
  both are off.
- When using **alsamixer**, press F5 to display more controls, and scroll right with arrow key as not all faders are visible in the console.